# jPList - jQuery Data Grid Controls jPList page jumps

Tags: javascript, jplist

I am using the jPList from 
http://jplist.com/

The problem i have is that when i click on page number or on any filter a pege jumps to top, i there solution for this problem.

Here is what I have for now

```
<div class="jplist-drop-down"
            data-control-type="items-per-page-drop-down"
            data-control-name="paging"
            data-control-action="paging"
            data-control-animate-to-top="true">
              <ul>
                <li><span data-number="4"> 4 po strani </span></li>
                <li><span data-number="8"> 8 po strani </span></li>
                <li><span data-number="16" data-default="true"> 16 po strani </span></li>
                <li><span data-number="24"> 24 po strani </span></li>
                <li><span data-number="all"> Prikaži sve </span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

When in dropdown i click on any value page jumps

Answer (score 0):

Animate to top - enabled by `data-control-animate-to-top="true"` attribute in control.

More options related to *animate to top*:

```
animateToTop: 'html, body'
animateToTop: 0 //in milliseconds (1000 ms = 1 sec)
```

For more options [see the documentation](http://jplist.com/documentation/js-settings).